# Is it ok to call std::basic_string::find on already moved string?

Tags: c++

According to [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), a moved `std::string` is in a "valid but unspecified state", which means that functions without preconditions can be used on the string. Is it ok to use `std::basic_string::find` on the unspecified string? Does `std::basic_string:find` have any precondition?

```
#include <string>
int main() {
  std::string str = "hello";
  auto s = std::move(str);
  str.find("world");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what possible use case you have for doing this.  I see no practical reason, since the object's state is unspecified.

Comment: It's ok but useless.

Comment: A possible example is iterating over a vector of strings with `find_if` and a condition using `find`, moving a string from the vector if the condition met and doing `find_if` again on the vector. In this case, we might call `find` on an unspecified element.

Comment: str will be in a valid state. Most likely a null string, but not guaranteed. The optimized code for strings could leave short strings in a different state than longer ones, for example.

Comment: Let's say it's allowed. But then the return value is unpredictable, so what's the point?

Comment: I'm surprised by your question: I would have pointed you towards the very place you linked yourself. In what way do you think your code differs from the code given as examples there?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of the purpose of move mechanics here. You shouldn't "move a string from the vector" and then `find_if` on that vector again. There is an "understanding move mechanics" question here waiting to be asked...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The example in the link says that `back` cannot be used on an moved string but `empty` can, but I'm not sure about `find`.

Comment: If you want an empty string to be left behind, then just move an empty string into the vector after moving the old one out.

Comment: So, It's not an UB to call `find` on a moved string (unlike `back`), but we shouldn't do that because the content of a moved string is unpredictable, right ?

Comment: What would be the runtime of `find` on the unspecified valid `string`?

Comment: @Sebastian For instance, when gathering strings that meets a condition from a vector by `move`ing the string from it and the condition includes `find`. (To do so, I'd think I need to iterating over the vector several times.)

Comment: With a sensible implementation, the result of moving from a string might be that the source string still contains the original text or it might be empty. If you don't know which, searching it is meaningless.

Comment: @PeteBecker If you discard the result of `find` after moving, it would not matter, what the result was. However, if the program is slowed down, as it 'points' to a 1GB string ...

Comment: @Sebastian -- if you discard the result of `find` after moving it is, as I said, meaningless.

Comment: @PeteBecker What do you mean by 'it' is meaningless? You have to possibly wait nevertheless, if the optimizer does not manage to remove the `find` call. (It has to detect that the result is discarded, even with possibly complicated program flow; it has to detect that `find` is a pure function; it has to create efficient assembly code out of the possibly complicated program flow, where moving and discarding are possibly only border cases.)

Comment: @Sebastian -- `find` has no side effects, so the only reason to call it is that you care about the value that it returns. If you discard the value, then there is no point in making the call in the first place. The call is meaningless.

Comment: @PeteBecker Only if you know that it is discarded, which is not always the case, depending on program flow. In this case perhaps (?) the OP can logically derive that the result of `find` is always later on discarded, when it was moved. Perhaps in the OP's case, it is not possible to or has other disadvantages to store this boolean information together with the string or it takes too much time to test the boolean around the call to `find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the description of `std::basic_string:find` in [[string.find]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.find):

> `constexpr size_type F(const charT* s, size_type pos) const;`
>
> has effects equivalent to:
> `return F(basic_­string_­view<charT, traits>(s), pos);`

which has the following effects

> Effects: Let `G` be the name of the function. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> basic_string_view<charT, traits> s = *this, sv = t; 
> return s.G(sv, pos);
> ```

which will construct `basic_string_view` from `*this`, which has [preconditions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/strings#string.view.cons-5) that `[str, str + len)` is a valid range, and since the moved string is *still* in a valid state, so this is OK.

Comment: Thank you for answering! BTW, is the return value of `find` on a moved string always `std::string::npos`? or unpredictable?

Comment: Unpredictable since it is in an unspecified state.

Comment: @wanwan If your string has been **moved** from the container, *it should no longer **be** in the container* (making this whole question moot). I still think you're abusing move semantics, but since you don't show a complete example, it's hard to tell. Move semantics are to optimize what would otherwise be a "copy **and delete**". So either you don't delete where you should, or you're moving where you should copy...